# django error no module named urls after sitemaps installation

Tags: django, django-urls, django-sitemaps

I'm getting the following error:

> File "/mysite/urls.py" in 
>     7. from commerce.sitemaps import CommerceSitemap
>
> File "/mysite/sitemaps.py" in 
>     3. from django.urls import reverse
>
> Exception Type: ImportError at / Exception Value: No module named urls
>   Request information: GET: No GET data

My installed apps look like:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'commerce',
]
```

My urls.py looks like:

```
sitemaps = {
    'commerce': CommerceSitemap,
}

url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import 'url'?

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

Also, I think urls should be declared inside a list called urlpatterns in order for Django to pick them up.

```
urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps},name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was a deprecation between django.urls in django 1.9 and 1.10 . I upgraded and this solved my problem.